# Why is the total voltage across my capacitor and load(ac motor) greater than the ac source voltage?

Tags: capacitor, induction-motor

Good morning all, I have been having issues with my circuit; I'm trying to create a regulator for my ac motor and the regulator type I went for is the capacitor regulator which I connected to an ac motor(induction motor) but for some reason, the voltage across my circuit is higher than the input voltage. Please can someone explain to me what is happening and give me a solution to it. Thank you.

Comment: It's called resonance.

Comment: You need to provide a circuit diagram.  There is a schematic editor built into the editor.  What type of induction motor?  Three-phase or single-phase.  Info on your regulator circuit?  The capacitor is supplying leading reactive power to the lagging inductive load.

Comment: It's a single-phase induction motor.